# How to uninstall MailChimp

Tags: installation

Please help me uninstall MailChimp.

I disabled all MailChimp component modules, then I clicked uninstall. I got no error messages.

I then deleted the MailChimp folder from Sites/All.

Finally I ran phpMyAdmin and searched for MailChimp. I then deleted everything having MailChimp in it, BUT MailChimp still appears (though disabled) when I click modules.

I'm trying to get rid of MailChimp because it does not work and because SimpleNews does not work. I'm think that they are fighting each other.

I'm using Adquia Dev Desktop on my Win 7 computer with Open Outreach distribution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you got all the module files? Normally they are placed in 'sites/all/modules' not 'sites/all' perhaps this was only the mailchimp library? But that should have been in 'sites/all/libraries'.

Did you flush the caches? This can be done via 'admin/config/development/performance'. 
Because it sounds like you deleted everything.

Disabled modules don't really cause any problems, is there a reason why you want to delete it fully?

Comment: I missed sites/all/libraries. I deleted it from there and deleted all database references. I flushed all caches, but MailChimp still shows up when I click Modules. I gave up on MailChimp because it wouldn't work. Then I found SimpleNews. Unfortunately SimpleNews does not work either. I thought that maybe the reason it didn't work was because MailChimp needed to be uninstalled. Maybe MailChimp was interfering with SimpleNews?

Comment: Normally they shouldn't interfere. Certainly not if mailchimp is disabled. The only thing that can happen then is that they use the same db tables but that's not possible if mailchimp has been uninstalled. Since uninstalling deletes all the DB items from a module. And very unlikely anyway.

Comment: OK. I'm a newbie to Drupal. I just start phpMyAdmin again and searched all tables for MailChimp. To my surprise it found 5 rows in the System table. sites/all/modules/mailchimp/mailchimp.module as well as ... mailchimp_activity, campaign, lists, and signup. There is also 1 row in the cache table: features_module_info. How can there be rows in the system table when the mailchimp folder has been deleted? I guess I really messed things up.

Answer (score 1):

The module will continue to be listed on the /admin/modules page as long as Drupal detects it on your filesystem within /sites/all/modules, /sites/default/modules, or another folder under /sites if you're running a multi-site setup. Just because the module is listed there doesn't mean it is enabled and running on the site.

Uninstalling modules is usually done the way you described it in the first line of your post. You go to /admin/modules to disable modules, then onto /admin/modules/uninstall to uninstall them. If the developer of the module did it correctly, you shouldn't have to do anything more than that. You will still see it listed in the modules page because it is still on your filesystem

I wouldn't recommend manually deleting anything out of the database unless you know exactly what it is that you're doing. You could mess things up When you disable and uninstall modules through the Drupal interface (or Drush), there are certain hook functions that get called which should remove data from the database.

What I would do is first is locate the module folder containing MailChimp. Ensure that you only have it in one place. If you had the module in different folders and only delete one, it will still be listed on the admin/modules page.

If you don't see it in those folders, re-install it. Then properly disable and uninstall it again the way you described WITHOUT touching the database yourself. This will probably undo any damage you could have caused in the database and ensure  that the data in the database is properly cleared out. Afterwards, delete the module folder from the filesystem and it should be gone.

Comment: OK. I used Windows Explorer to search for mailchimp. It found mailchimp in C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev\docroot\sites\all\modules. I am using Acquia Dev Desktop and have this site both on my local Win 7 computer and stored in Acquia's cloud. What is the relationship between C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev\docroot\sites\all and C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\openoutreach-7.x-1.19\sites?

Comment: Should I go ahead and delete the mailchimp folder from C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev\docroot\sites\all, then re-install mailchimp then uninstall mailchimp? I'm a newbie so I want to understand what's happening here. Thanks!

Comment: Open Outreach is a Drupal distribution. Since it doesn't have the Mailchimp module in it, I wouldn't worry about it. If you had a site using Open Outreach that needed MailChimp, the 'sites' folder under Open Outreach would have a folder for your site which would have its own modules folder.

Comment: Since you still have the MailChimp module on your filesystem, Drupal is still detecting it. Since you played around with your database, what you should do now is this:

1. Re-enable the MailChimp module in Drupal on the /admin/modules page. If there are multiple Mailchimp modules, enable them all.
2. Disable the module(s)
3. Uninstall the module(s)
4. Delete the MailChimp folder in Windows Explorer

What that will do is run the functions that will correctly clean the database of MailChimp, and possibly find anything you missed.

Comment: OK. I followed your instructions. When I got to step 4 I deleted mailchimp from C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev\docroot\sites\all\libraries and C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev\docroot\sites\all\modules. There were no mailchimp folders in C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\openoutreach-7.x-1.19\sites\all. Mailchimp is now gone! Please help me understand the purpose of the C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev folder. It appears that lots of stuff is duplicated here from C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\openoutreach-7.x-1.19.

Comment: Does the C:\Users\Sam\Sites\devdesktop\columbiablooms-dev folder have anything to do with multisite or is it necessary for Acquia Dev Desktop? Having stuff duplicated seems a waste and causes confusion for a newbie like myself.

Comment: I don't know what columbiablooms is and I'm not too familiar with Acquia's Dev Desktop :\ It sounds like a custom site. Did you inherit the project?

Comment: Also, if my answer solved your problem, could you mark it?

Comment: I'll start a new question. Thanks for your help! I did not inherit the site. I'm building it from scratch for our local beautification effort.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for marking the other person's answer as the accepted solution...

Answer (score 0):

Check your field list (/admin/reports/fields) and remove any Mailchimp Subscription fields you find.